# Sonarqube test case rule does not take @Test annotation into account

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, sonarqube, junit4

Sonarqube generates issues as

> TestCases should contain tests

regarding that test classes does not have any tests inside but there are methods marked with `@Test` annotation and classes annotated with `@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)`.

I have no problem running TestSuites and importing unit test and coverage reports into sonarqube. I checked sonarqube source code and it should find annotations but unfortunately it does not. Rule id for the mentioned issue is S2187.

Is there a configuration for this rule to find annotated methods or is a known issue?

Edit - config:

```
sonar.projectKey=x
sonar.projectName=x
sonar.projectVersion=1.0 
sonar.modules=a,b,c
a.sonar.projectBaseDir=modules/a
b.sonar.projectBaseDir=modules/b
c.sonar.projectBaseDir=modules/c
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=test
sonar.java.binaries=../**/classes/production,../**/classes/test
sonar.java.libraries=../../libraries/repository
sonar.junit.reportsPath=junit/
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reporthPath=coverage/jacoco.exec
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: How are you running the analysis ? maven or sonar-runner ? if the latter can you share your configuration  ? The coverage report and unit test results import have nothing to do with this rule and is thus not relevant for this issue.

Comment: I am running the analysis over sonar-runner and using sonar-java plugin version is 3.3 and i added configuration to question aswell.

Comment: Tried with sonar-java plugin version 3.4 and it did not help either.

Comment: Does the libraries/repository contains the junit jar ?

Comment: No i was excluding it, will try to put the jar in repository path.

Comment: The bytecode of junit has to be provided in order for the semantic analysis to resolve the @Test annotation.

Comment: tried with junit jar in repository but it did not help either then i tried with 5.1.1 server version but result is same unfortunately then i checked the sonar runner log from the file which generated by 'sonar-runner -X -Dsonar.verbose=true > sonar-runner.log' command but there is no test related error either.

Comment: FYI I see a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32083139/944849) with the Eclipse plugin.  I asked a separate question so I could provide relevant details; it was too long for a comment.

Comment: thanks i have fixed my issue with an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fixed by correctly setting sonar.java.test.libraries/binaries attributes as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32197912/343806. They were not not in the runner configuration and after adding raised issues in sonarqube results marked as fixed.