# SonarQube test case rule does not take @Test annotation into account with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sonarqube

I am seeing an issue similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30860378/944849).  When running `mvn sonar:sonar` as a Jenkins post-build action on a Maven project, @Test and @Ignore annotations in JUnit tests are recognized properly.  When I run a SonarQube preview on the same project via the SonarQube Eclipse plugin, the annotations are *not* recognized and there are (erroneous) Major bug issues shown.

I have followed the directions for installing and configuring the Eclipse plugin [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) and [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+Eclipse).  Am I missing configuration somewhere?

- SonarQube server 5.1.2 with Java plugin 3.4
- Eclipse Luna 4.4.0
- m2e 1.6.1.20150625
- SonarQube Integration for Eclipse 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE (4 features)
- Apache Maven 3.2.2 (for both Jenkins and Eclipse)

---

Update:

My multi-module project is structured like this:

```
Top level aggregator POM (is not the parent)
    Project parent POM
    Module 1 (extends project parent)
    Module 2 (extends project parent)
```

When the top level directory is expanded, there is no Maven Dependencies child directory, because the top level POM doesn't include any dependencies (only a `modules` block).  I was running the SonarQube analysis at the top level, so the SonarQube Eclipse plugin didn't have the dependencies needed, and I saw the errors.  If I run the analysis on one of the individual modules, I see only the expected errors, not the extra ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is usually caused by missing test classpath (missing or bad sonar.java.test.libraries/binaries). Updating to SQ Java plugin 3.5 will at least hide the problem thanks to https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1193.

Update:

If you are using m2e, when importing a multi module Maven project you should get one Eclipse project per Maven module. And then you should run SonarQube analysis on each leaf modules.

Comment: Aha, thanks to your tip I see what's happening.  I will update my question with more details about the project structure.

Comment: Should I be able to run an Eclipse SonarQube analysis on a top-level module for a project structured like I described above and get correct results?  Or must we always run SonarQube on individual modules (that have Maven Dependencies directories)?

Comment: If you are using m2e, when importing as Maven project you should get one Eclipse project per Maven module. And then you should run SonarQube analysis on each leaf modules.

Comment: Thanks - your last comment is the real answer.  If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.  Please consider adding "analysis should be run on the leaf modules" or something like it to the Eclipse SonarQube documentation.

Comment: How do you set a test classpath in a Maven project?